# MongoDB adding month to Date

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So, this is driving me nuts and I'm not sure if it's a bug or if I'm missing something obvious.  Can someone please explain to me why a month is added to the following statement in mongo 2.0.2

```
# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.2
> new Date()
ISODate("2012-02-19T04:58:56.988Z")
> new Date(2012, 02, 19, 04, 58, 56)
ISODate("2012-03-19T04:58:56Z")
> new Date(2012, 01, 19, 04, 58, 56)
ISODate("2012-02-19T04:58:56Z")
```

Notice how a month is added when I specify the date. Whiskey Tango Foxtrot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB uses JavaScript as its interface language. The `month` in the JavaScript Date constructor is zero based. From the [fine manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **`month`**
>   Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.

Note the *0 for January*. This sort of thing is one of the reasons that MongoDB tends to use their own [`ISODate` function](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Overview+-+The+MongoDB+Interactive+Shell#Overview-TheMongoDBInteractiveShell-Dates) instead of `new Date`:

> [...] ISODate is a thin wrapper around the Date constructor to fix some of it's shortcomings. It returns a normal Date object with all of the normal methods that javascript Date methods support.